# How to access nativeElement of div´s children

Tags: angular

I am getting hold of a parent divs children and I am looping through these children. I need to access the nativeElement of each child.

```
 let children = Array.from(this.myParentDiv.nativeElement.children);
 for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    console.log(children[i]); // Prints <div....
 console.log(children[i].nativeElement); // Prints undefined
}
```

How can I access the nativeElement of each children?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`children[i]` is the native element it self there is no property `nativeElement` specified in the dom.

and `nativeElement` is a property used by angular to access the native element regardless the platform (mobile , browser ..)

Comment: Didn't realize I could call the properties directly on the children[i]